Removing elements with particular substrings
I am trying to create a set of all bit strings of length n that do not contain consecutive zeros. While I could do this recursively, I wanted to create a non-recursive method as well.
While there are several ways to do this, I decided to create a list of all the strings and then remove the ones with two consecutive zeros. I tried simply checking if '00' was contained in each bit string. If it was, then I would remove it. However, it missed a lot of the double zero cases.
Below is another technique I tried, which eliminated more of them, but still missed some. I also tried checking through each string to see if num[k]==0 and num[k+1]==0 and, if so, remove it... but this did not work.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
def bit_string(n):
    list = []
    if n == 0:
        return list
    else:
        list.append(0)
        list.append(1)
        i = 1
        while i < n:
            temp_list = []
            for num in list:
                num = str(num)
                temp_list.append(num+'1')
                temp_list.append(num+'0')
                list = temp_list
            i = i + 1
        for k in range(2,n+1):
            for num in list:
                if '0'*k in num:
                    list.remove(num)
    list = set(list)
    return list

print(bit_string(4))


Don't name a variable list by the way. It prevents you from using it to reference the builtin.

I think this is because you modify the list while you're iterating over it.  Don't do that.  Strange things happen.

"However, it missed a lot of the double zero cases." Maybe you should look into why.

@Anerdw I agree that I could have used a better name than list.

@ScottHunter That was my purpose of posting here. I can not figure out why it is missing some of them.

@JohnGordon do you have any suggestions as to another method? Thanks

Yes, see my answer below.

"I tried simply checking if '00' was contained in each bit string. If it was, then I would remove it. However, it missed a lot of the double zero cases." This happens for the reason in the linked duplicate. "Below is another technique I tried" - that's the same technique that you described in words, failing for the same reason: the loop to do the removal will skip over an element after it does a removal. I guess the supposed "new" idea is to check for longer runs of zeros as well, but that (a) is not necessary and (b) is not why it was failing.

(The question about directly generating the bit strings is a different question that should be asked separately. The question here is about a specific problem encountered while taking the filtering approach, and the actual generation used to produce the to-be-filtered data is irrelevant. As such, the question is a duplicate.)

Let's start by getting rid of a whole bunch of indentation and simplifying the start.
def bit_string(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    
    list = [0, 1]
    i = 1

    while i < n:
        temp_list = []
        for num in list:
            num = str(num)
            temp_list.append(num+'1')
            temp_list.append(num+'0')
            list = temp_list
        i = i + 1

    for k in range(2,n+1):
        for num in list:
            if '0'*k in num:
                list.remove(num)

    list = set(list)
    return list

That's slightly easier to read and understand.
Your biggest issue is that you're trying to modify list while iterating over it. Let's fix this by instead generating a new list.
def bit_string(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    
    list = [0, 1]
    i = 1

    while i < n:
        temp_list = []
        for num in list:
            num = str(num)
            temp_list.append(num+'1')
            temp_list.append(num+'0')
            list = temp_list
        i = i + 1

    new_list = []
    for k in range(2,n+1):
        for num in list:
            if '0'*k not in num:
                new_list.append(num)

    list = set(new_list)
    return list

But this fails because you're iterating over the list multiple times, and then appending in elements that don't have 3 or more consecutive zeros. We really only need to check for '00', not '000 anyway.
def bit_string(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    
    list = [0, 1]
    i = 1

    while i < n:
        temp_list = []
        for num in list:
            num = str(num)
            temp_list.append(num+'1')
            temp_list.append(num+'0')
            list = temp_list
        i = i + 1

    new_list = []
    for num in list:
        if '00' not in num:
            new_list.append(num)

    list = set(new_list)
    return list

A further refinement is to replace most of that end of your function with a simple set comprehension and your while loop with a for loop over a range.
def bit_string(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []

    list = [0, 1]

    for _ in range(1, n):
        temp_list = []
        for num in list:
            num = str(num)
            temp_list.append(num+'1')
            temp_list.append(num+'0')
            list = temp_list

    return {num for num in list if '00' not in num}

We're still modifying list while iterating over it, so list = temp_list needs to come out of that loop.
def bit_string(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []

    list = [0, 1]

    for _ in range(1, n):
        temp_list = []
        for num in list:
            num = str(num)
            temp_list.append(num+'1')
            temp_list.append(num+'0')
        list = temp_list

    return {num for num in list if '00' not in num}


Most bit strings do contain consecutive zeros, so it's quite wasteful to produce all and then filter them. Better simply don't append a zero to strings that already end with a zero (Attempt This Online!):
result = ['']
for _ in range(n):
    result = [
        s + b
        for s in result
        for b in ('1' if s.endswith('0') else '01')
    ]

Another version, keeping track of the set Z of strings ending with a zero and the set N of strings not ending with a zero (Attempt This Online!):
Z, N = [], ['']
for _ in range(n):
    Z, N = (
        [s + '0' for s in N],
        [s + '1' for s in Z + N]
    )
result = Z + N

That btw also makes it easy to just count them (Attempt This Online!):
Z, N = 0, 1
for _ in range(n):
    Z, N = N, Z + N
result = Z + N

And now you might recognize that as the Fibonacci numbers.
Trying to make sense of why it's Fibonaccis, I realized another way: For a certain length, you get all strings ending with 1 by appending 1 to any string one bit shorter. And (except for length 1) you get all strings ending with 0 by appending 10 to any string two bits shorter. As code (Attempt This Online!):
A, B = [], ['']
for _ in range(n):
    A, B = B, ([s+'10' for s in A] or ['0']) + [s+'1' for s in B]
result = B

(Test code, also embedded here as HTML comment)

@KellyBundy While these work, my goal here is actually to give a sample script for students that are learning about forming bit strings and recursion. The goal was to have a non-recursive program that would create bitstrings of length n that also "looked mathematical" so that they could follow what is happening. Since there is a large mixture of programming experience (and I am not a programmer myself), I wanted to present it is an easy to follow way for a general audience.

@GregoryVarner You should mention your goal / motivation in your question. Otherwise, people are free to provide answers that they consider to be suitable both for you and any future readers of your question.

@GregoryVarner Ok, then these aren't for you but just for other readers, that's alright :-). I could've told you the bugs in your code and how to fix them, but it would still be inefficient and much code. And since the question explicitly welcomes "Any suggestions", this answer has mine.

@GregoryVarner Or more likely, since your main bug and title are the same old boring question that far too many people have already asked, I would've closed this as yet another duplicate. I only didn't because the question/task allows other solutions.

@KellyBundy No offense intended and I should have been a bit more clear on the purpose. I appreciate the suggestions.

@GregoryVarner None taken, it's all good :-). Btw for n=0 your result doesn't have the empty string and for n=1 you return ints instead of strings. Better start with list = [''] and remove the then unnecessary lines and indentation.

You want to start with all the possible combinations of 0 and 1 with a length of 4:
0000
0001
0010
0011
...
1110
1111

This is called a cartesian product.
Luckily, Python includes a function to generate exactly this sequence.  You don't have to do the work yourself.
Then you can simply take all of the items from that sequence which do not contain 00.
from itertools import product
result = []
for p in product("01", repeat=4):
    # p is a tuple like ("0", "0", "0", "1")
    # condense that into a string like "0001"
    strp = ''.join(p)
    if '00' not in strp:
        result.append(strp)

Granted, this generates a lot of strings that ultimately just get discarded, so it is not as fast as it might be.  But I think it's worth it in terms of code clarity and readability -- good code should be obviously correct when you read it.

"it's worth it in terms of code clarity and readability" I beg to differ, since an implementation that is not wasteful isn't that difficult to come up with.

How about this? We don't generate strings containing "00" at all.
def bit_string(n):
    stack = [""]
    
    while stack:
        buf = stack.pop()
        if len(buf) == n:
            yield buf
        else:
            for i in "0", "1":
                if buf and buf[-1] == i == "0":  # Skip consecutive "0"s
                    continue
                stack.append(buf + i)
                
for n in range(1, 5):
    for b in bit_string(n):
        print(b)

Output:
0
1
01
10
11
010
011
101
110
111
0101
0110
0111
1010
1011
1101
1110
1111


An iterative solution that only generates valid strings:
def bit_string(n):
    s = "1"
    backtrack = False
    while len(s)>0:
        if len(s)==n: # We found a solution!
            yield s
            backtrack = True # Start baktracking
        if backtrack:
            if s[-1]=="1" and (len(s)==1 or s[-2] != "0"): 
                # If current string ends w/ a 1 but not 01, replace the trailing 1 w/ a 0 and stop backtracking
                s = s[:-1]+"0"
                backtrack = False
            else: 
                # Remove last bit & keep backtracking
                s = s[:-1]
        else:
            # Always safe to add a 1 to the end
            s = s + "1"


Trying to stay close to your attempt and just fix your removal bug and the others:
def bit_string(n):
    list = ['']
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        temp_list = []
        for num in list:
            temp_list.append(num + '1')
            temp_list.append(num + '0')
        list = temp_list
        i = i + 1
    for num in list.copy():
        if '00' in num:
            list.remove(num)
    return list

print(bit_string(4))

Attempt This Online!
Still very inefficient, though, so I'd recommend my other solutions.
